# Adding a Karaf Feature

Tags: apache-karaf

To add a "feature" to an instance of Apache Karaf, one option is to use (as described at https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/provisioning). What I don't understand, and can't find documented anywhere, is: where does this feature get added behind the scenes?

To clarify, after I *repo-add* a feature and then shut down Karaf, that feature persists the next time I start up Karaf - even though that feature does not show up in *org.apache.karaf.features.repos.cfg*. That being the case, how does Karaf know that I've added that feature? Is there another config file somewhere that the feature has gotten added to upon my issuing the *repo-add*?

Answer (score 0):

As noted at http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_feature_and_resolver, 
"*The features state is stored in the Apache Karaf cache (in the KARAF_DATA folder).*" Specifically, that location is found in your Karaf directory at location ...\data\cache. At that location you will find separate directories for each bundle (e.g., *\data\cache\bundle123*). In each of those directories you will find a file, *bundle.info*, which contains the path to the maven repository that pertains to that feature.

Comment: Just to clarify .. org.apache.karaf.features.repos.cfg does not store the feature repos you installed. It is just a map of feature repo name -> feature repo uri so you can install these repos with their shot name